# elasticsearch error : failed to parse

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `elasticsearch 2.3.3` on windows,
after installing `elasticsearch` and 
`elasticsearch-analysis-ik`,

I tried the example in the documentation of `elasticsearch-analysis-ik`, https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik ,like this:

1、create a index,it's ok.

```
$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/index 
{"acknowledged":true}
```

2、create a mapping,it's ok.

```
$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index/fulltext/_mapping -d'
> {
>     "fulltext": {
>              "_all": {
>             "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
>             "search_analyzer": "ik_max_word",
>             "term_vector": "no",
>             "store": "false"
>         },
>         "properties": {
>             "content": {
>                 "type": "string",
>                 "store": "no",
>                 "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
>                 "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
>                 "search_analyzer": "ik_max_word",
>                 "include_in_all": "true",
>                 "boost": 8
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   587  100    21  100   566    677  18258 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 18258{"                                                                                   acknowledged":true}
```

3.index some docs. Error here,as follows:

```
$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index/fulltext/1 -d'
> {"content":""}
> '
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   416  100   372  100    44   4769    564 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5904{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [content]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [content]","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xc0\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@324c601f; line: 2, column: 15]"}},"status":400}
```